# Парсинг яндекс-такси

Tags: php, парсер, яндекс-такси

Хотел попробовать спарсить цену на [сайте](https://taxi.yandex.ru/)

Чтобы выполнить [запрос](https://taxi.yandex.ru/3.0/routestats/), который отвечает за ответ цены, необходимо сначала получить уникальный id. 
Id можно получить по этой [ссылке](https://taxi.yandex.ru/3.0/launch/), но для начала необходимо сформировать куку yandex_uid.

Итого, получается 3 этапа.

1. Делаем запрос на `https://taxi.yandex.ru/`, получаем куку yandex_uid
2. Отправляем эту куку на `https://taxi.yandex.ru/3.0/launch/` , получаем уникальный `id`
3. Отправляем `id`, координаты и т.п на `https://taxi.yandex.ru/3.0/routestats/`, получаем цену

Проблема возникает на шаге 2. 
Постоянно получаю ошибку 400.

Вот код:

```
$client->createRequest()
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->setUrl('https://taxi.yandex.ru/3.0/launch/')
        ->setHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'])
        ->addHeaders(['Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br'])
        ->addHeaders(['Accept-Language' => 'ru_RU'])
        ->addHeaders(['Cache-Control' => 'no-cache'])
        ->addHeaders(['Connection' => 'keep-alive'])
        ->addHeaders(['Content-Length' => ob_get_length()])
        ->addHeaders(['Cookie' => 'yandexuid='.$cookies->getValue('yandexuid')])
        ->addHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'application/json'])
        ->addHeaders(['Host' => 'taxi.yandex.ru'])
        ->addHeaders(['Origin' => 'https://taxi.yandex.ru'])
        ->addHeaders(['Pragma' => 'no-cache'])
        ->addHeaders(['Referer' => 'https://taxi.yandex.ru/'])
        ->addHeaders(['User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'])
        ->addHeaders(['X-Compress' => null])
        ->addHeaders(['X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'])
        ->send();
```

Что я делаю не так?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А если отключать по одному заголовку и проверять - пробовал?

Comment: 15! вариантов..